# Can the pi2go Lite be programmed to count steps?

Tags: python

The Pi 2 go lite has IR light sensors on each wheel. I am wondering it is possible to count each step.

Example: It turns left or right and counts how many steps it took with the left or right wheel. If he goes forward how many steps did it take?

If it makes it easier per rotation of a tire it takes 16 "Steps" per revolution.

```
import pi2go, time   
import sys  
import tty  
import termios  
import time  
pi2go.init()  

def stepCount():  
   countL += 0  
   countR += 0  

running = True  
countL = 0  
countR = 0  

speed = 60  
try:  
   pi2go.stepForward(60,10)  
   print stepCount  

finally:  
   pi2go.cleanup()
```

the output is not the same everytime. here are examples of the output.  0x76a65530 or 0x76abb530

Comment: The [pi2go.py library](http://4tronix.co.uk/pi2go/pi2go.py) has functions for stepForward(speed, counts), stepReverse(speed, counts), stepSpinL(speed, stepCounts) and stepSpinR(speed, counts) that allow you to specify how many steps you'd like the robot to go. Might it be easier just to use those, rather than arbitrarily counting steps?

Comment: I know about those. I'm just trying to get a step count so I can make a "map" of a room.

Answer (score 1):

The pi2go.py library's `wheelCount()` method is run continuously on a thread, and (I'm fairly sure) sets the global variables `countL` and `countR` to indicate how many times the IR sensors pick up an input. You should be able to count the number of steps by setting `countL` and `countR` to 0, then running `turnForward(speed, speed)` for some amount of time, then re-reading the values of countL and countR.

Comment: If i use countL or countR the out put is wierd 2 examples of the output are 0x76abb530 and 0x76a65530 but I use the same variable every single time.

Comment: It sounds like you might be misusing Python - take a wee look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10844230/why-does-this-python-method-return-a-memory-address .